# SQL Statement fetching only latest connected entries of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the bad title, I could not come up with anything better...

I simply need some help formulating an SQL statement. Unfortunately my SQL is a bit rusty. I attached a simplified example of my situation (ER-Model).

[image]

As you can see there, I have 4 tables. Customers, Product, Licenses and Support.
A License is always issued for a specific product and assigned to a specific customer. A customer can hold have one or many licenses.
Initially I only wanted the combined information of the tables Customers, Prodcut and Licenses. So far so good, that is easy, I only need to ask for

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers,
     Product,
     Licenses
WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Licenses.CustomerID
  AND Product.ProductID = Licenses.ProductID
```

But now I need also to add some data from the Support table. I want for each entry from the previous statement (for each license) now also the description and the date of the **LAST** support case (if any) that was tied to the respective LicenseKey (only the last one per LicenseKey not all). The SupportID is a running number so one can sort by that.

I know I could also ask for all cases and filter the received date in my application but unfortunately network traffic should be kept to a minimum.

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi.. you are my only hope...

Comment: Please avoid comma separated JOINS. They are discouraged nowadays!

Comment: No not a school assignment. Work related.
As I mentioned, I had it already working but the network traffic was not acceptable for colleagues who had to use the tool via VPN from home.

Comment: I would avoid them but as I said, I am not too experienced with SQL in the first place. So please anyone feel free to optimize the hell out of my original statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` just in case there are no support cases for a license.

The `NOT EXISTS` is there to return a support case only of there are no later for the same license.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers c
  JOIN Licenses l ON c.CustomerID = l.CustomerID
  JOIN Product p ON p.ProductID = l.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN Support s1 ON s1.LicenseKey = l.LicenseKey
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Support s2
                  where s2.LicenseKey = s1.LicenseKey
                    and s2.Date > s1.Date)
```

**Note**: Now modern explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: GREAT! That was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Hmm... unfortunately the query is a bit slow now... If anyone can think of a way how to improve the above statement I would be very grateful. If not then I will have to live with that I guess.

Just as a side-node, My table of Support cases has > 30.000 entries. And my table of Licenses about 700